# How to find out what is svchost is doing

Tags: windows, service

I have a problem running some automated tests because the CPU usage gets high at some point randomly. So I added this call to my code to see the process causing the high CPU usage:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime
```

This gives me a list of processes and thier CPU usage. Unfortunately the process is this:

```
svchost#11          100
```

I know svchost is only a host for a service. So is there an easy way to get a more detailed description of what svchost is doing in a command line so I can integrate it in my code? Any tools like Process Explorer are not useful because they are controlled by a GUI. I need something I can put in a system() call.

Btw I already disabled automated updates - so it has to be something different.

Comment: More on this topic can be fount at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588575/how-to-get-all-services-name-that-runs-under-svchost-exe-process)

Answer (score 6):

This is what I wanted:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!