# How to get all services name that runs under "svchost.exe" process

Tags: c#, wmi

Using below WMI query I am able to get all services names,

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service ")
```

Also, when I'm running below command in command prompt, it will give all the Process Id (PID) and Service Name,

```
tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq svchost.exe"
```

I want WMI/C# way to find all the service which runs under "svchost.exe" process?

And Is there any other way other than WMI?

Comment: I think you're looking for a rather ugly solution, basically you'll end up calling (unmanaged) DLLs using pinvoke. I think the ABI reference you want is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx .It will *probably* be less of a hassle to just call a powershell script or something in the background.

Comment: A better question: what are you doing with this information? Depending on that, there may be simpler/better ways even than getting what you're getting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all of the services using the same code as you did and then just iterate through them and check if their `PathName` is something like `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe ... "`. That would be the easiest way.

Another option would be to rewrite your query into something like this :

```
string q = "select * from Win32_Service where PathName LIKE \"%svchost.exe%\"";
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a batch-file which I trigger with C# and catch the return value
of the list.

The solution could look like this:

myBatch.bat:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe"
```

C# program:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "myBatch.bat";
 p.Start();
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 Console.Write(output);
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the **ServiceController.getServices** method?

Normally you would get the processes via the **Process.GetProcesses** method. The documentation states though:

> Multiple Windows services can be loaded within the same instance of the Service Host process (svchost.exe). GetProcesses does not identify those individual services; for that, see GetServices.

If you need more information about the serices, you have to rely on the WMI, but not to iterate through them.

So I would suggest you use this to examine the processes

```
foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
{
   if (scTemp.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("  Service :        {0}", scTemp.ServiceName);
      Console.WriteLine("    Display name:    {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);

     // if needed: additional information about this service.
     ManagementObject wmiService;
     wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" +
     scTemp.ServiceName + "'");
     wmiService.Get();
     Console.WriteLine("    Start name:      {0}", wmiService["StartName"]);
     Console.WriteLine("    Description:     {0}", wmiService["Description"]);
   }
}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a(v=vs.110).aspx)